# How to config and sync logs of two WAR files in a single log file using log4j 1.2.7?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, war

I have multiple WAR files (WAR-A, WAR-B and WAR-C) for which I want to have all logs into a single log file "ABC.log". I have created three "log4j.xml" with the same configurations for each WAR file. Now, the log4j is working but it is writing all the logs in a very haphazard and non-organized manner. Means they are not in proper sequence.

Logs of WAR-A and WAR-C are appearing at the start of the file while the logs of WAR-B are appearing at the end of the file. They should have to be in a sequence ideally. Also the new file is not creating up upon reaching the defined "MaxFileSize".

One more thing, if I remove the "log4j.xml" configuration file from WAR-B then WAR-A and WAR-C logs are appearing in right manner. But, in this way I'm losing the WAR-B logs coz I have removed the log4j.xml.

My log4j configurations are:

```
<!-- Appenders -->  

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="500KB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="50" />
    <param name="file" value="c:/logs/ABC.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

For the reference, I am using Wildfly 9.0.2 as my application server. Please share your thoughts how I can fix this issue. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to set `append` to `true`?

Comment: Yes, I did with WAR-A log4j configurations and it was working correctly as expected but the issue of not creating the new file after reaching 500KB was not fixed with this.